# 32m 39m being displayed in command prompt with list of all commands when accessing php artisan

Tags: laravel

I have downloaded a certain version of Laravel from GitHub manually as it wasn't getting installed using composer. The problem I am facing is that when I type any command in `php artisan` all the commands are preceded by weird looking numbers namely, `32m` and in the end appended by number `39m`. I Googled and found that maybe this was due to the reason I manually installed Laravel from Git. I don't have Github on the PC I am using Laravel on my Windows machine having Windows 10. I want to get rid of these numbers as they make it hard to see the commands.

#### Please check out the image

[image: Command prompt]

Comment: That unicode stuff i guess they are symbols.

Comment: @Jigs1212 How to get rid of them?

Comment: try using git bash

Comment: I don't have git installed on my PC besides I am not proficient with GitHub. Can you please give me a work around?

Comment: just install git, it will give u git bash just like cmd use commands there.

Comment: Those characters are being begin and end markers for a text range which will be colored in a specific way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should download the git in window system from below link.**

https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: Thanks, will do that, Any particular commands to get rid of this problem I am facing?

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe Thanks for upvote. Feel free to accept this as answer if our solution addressed your concern.

Comment: Will do but plz let me know some good resources to learn Git Bash and Git in general.

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe Follow this Documents.(i.e. https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial)

Answer (score 0):

What version of composer do you have? Because in order for you to have the `php` interface in your command line you need to install it using `composer` so what im trying to say is maybe there is something wrong with the composer.

P.S.

I downloaded `laravel` from https://github.com/laravel/laravel manually and installed latest version of `composer` and I didnt get the unicode strings.

---

What branch of laravel you cloned? master? 
To check the branch of the laravel you clone `git status` but you will need to download **git**

If you will push using the `git` I recommend to use the command

`git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git`

Comment: There is no problem with the composer, I downloaded v5.6.12 using composer and successfully installed it and after that went down to instaling v5.2.15 which couldn't get installed via composer so I manually had to download the package and then update composer. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tags

Answer (score 0):

open cmd as an admin and enter the following command:

> reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console /v VirtualTerminalLevel /t REG_DWORD
> /d 0x00000001 /f

close the cmd and run `php artisan` in a new command prompt

for more information you can take a look at
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5255355/How-to-Put-Color-on-Windows-Console