# Confusion in laravel artisan command

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

My xampp is install in windows 7 E: drive.
In there i have in htdocs, i have installed a fresh laravel.
When i do artisan command inside my project folder it gives me correct output but with that correct output it brings some unwanted characters like [32m, [39m etc etc. i am typing those console command below:

```
Ashiq@win-ashiq MINGW64 /e/xampp/htdocs/lv_proj/blog
$ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework [32m6.6.0[39m

Ashiq@win-ashiq MINGW64 /e/xampp/htdocs/lv_proj/blog
$ php artisan serve
[32mLaravel development server started:[39m http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

How can i get rid of these **[32m**, **[39m** characters from my console command?

Thanks.

Comment: Those look like control characters, and are used to style text on a console, eg coloured text or bold, etc.  If you are seeing them raw it suggests your console doesn't support them, or something is interfering with them.

Comment: I am using windows 7 and normally i run command from GIT bash.
From GIT bash i get this type of characters somehow. Now i use windows powershell and it solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Artisan detects which OS you're using and sends formatting characters accordingly. Instead of using MINGW bash (which is GNU/Linux like command prompt), use Windows's built-in CMD.

Hit start button + R, type `cmd.exe` then run:

```
cd /d project-path
php artisan inspire
```

Gibberish should be gone :)

Answer (score -3):

Install GIT and problem should disappear.
[GIT Download](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

Comment: Already GIT is installed @hmrneves

Comment: @ashique, I got this problem awhile ago and I solve it with the tips in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685722/32m-39m-being-displayed-in-command-prompt-with-list-of-all-commands-when-accessi

Comment: Why do you think git will help the display of control characters from PHP on the console? I'm afraid this makes no sense at all.

Comment: Yes, I downvoted - even if this is the answer, without any explanation it is a low-quality answer.